# Print pandas df with style.format in iPython

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'letters':('A', 'B', 'C'),
    'numbers':(0.1111, 0.2222, 0.3333)
}).set_index('letters')
df.style.format('{:.2f}')
```

Result:

```
Out[4]: <pandas.io.formats.style.Styler at 0x7f963f826eb8>
```

What I want:

Something similar to the default Jupyter output:

[image: jupyter_output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is using the `formatters` or `float_format` keyword of `df.to_string`

```
>>> print(df.to_string(float_format=lambda x: '{:.2f}'.format(x)))
         numbers
letters         
A           0.11
B           0.22
C           0.33
```

`float_format` will apply a function to all floats to format, while formatters can accept a list or dict to format specific columns in the dataframe.